# T-SQL: Exclude Columns from a SELECT statement based on string

Tags: sql, sql-server

My overall goal is to create new tables by selecting columns in existing tables with certain patterns/tags in their column names. This is in SQL Server.

For example, I have a common need to get all contact information out of a company table, and into its own contact table.

I haven't been able to find a programmatic approach in SQL to express excluding columns from a `SELECT` statement based on string.

When looking to options like the `COL_NAME` function, those require an ID arg, which kills that option for me.

Wishing there was something built in that could work like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COL_NAME() LIKE 'FLAG%'
```

Any ideas? Open to anything! Thanks!!

Comment: join to the `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` tables and use a `where` clause or just **not select them in your select list**. seems to be the easiest solution anyhow.

Comment: What you are describing is almost a textbook example of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Gary :)  It would be very helpful if you posted the `Create Table` command for your source table, the table that you want to create from it, and the criteria by which you select your columns.  Also, is this a "one-time-only" project, or is this something that you need to do regularly?  If it's a "one-time-only" project, you might be better off just sucking it up and doing it manually - with a decent text editor, it might not be that bad.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is indeed a common need for me, so manually excluding the column names wouldn't be a viable long-term option. I have been using workarounds to generate queries by copy pasting in between but am hoping for a more stable/formulaic option.

Comment: I can give dynamic SQL a shot like a couple have already suggested here, but still was hoping there was a more efficient way to reference column ID's or names in queries dynamically without beating around the bush ;/

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And can you provide an example of what you have now and what you're trying to get to? I do think Sean may be right. What is the overall goal of what you're trying to do?

Comment: SQL SERVER Developer Edition | Version: 14.0.1000.169

The goal is to form new tables by using data from existing tables within the same DB. In order to keep track of the target cols for the move to the new table, the cols have been labeled with a flag in their name, in hopes to use the flag to filter by string. The source data is from flat files; there is a mapping exercise included, which relates to the relabeling & flagging.

Answer (score 1):

One trick could be to firstly using the following code to get the column names you desire:

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='tbl' and column_name like 'FLAG%'
```

Then concatenate them into a comma-delimited string and finally create a dynamic sql query using the created string as the column names.